# the existence of solution in a system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in finding conditions under which solutions $y$ exist in the following *system* of ordinary differential equations:

$$ \begin{align*} \dot y(t) &= f(t,y(t)) \in \mathbb{R}^n, \\ y(0) &= y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n. \end{align*} $$

That is, I would like to know the (formal) references of, say, the Picard–Lindelöf Theorem or the Peano Existence Theorem for the vector-valued function case. My only interest is in the existence (and not in the uniqueness), and if I am correct, the Peano Existence Theorem for the vector-valued case would give me the answer. If I am wrong, references for relevant results would be greatly appreciated.

This may be a basic question, but all the references I found consider the $n=1$ case. Thank you very much!

Comment: The Picard-Lindelof Theorem and Peano Existence Theorem go through perfectly fine for $n$-dimensional systems. Here is a reference: https://www.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/555/555_notes/exist.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You can find conditions for the existence and uniqueness of solutions to the above system in this reference: "Nonlinear Systems" by Hassan K. Khalil, Chapter 3, Theorems 3.1 and 3.2.

Comment: I think it would be more useful if you post the 'answer' and give the reference at the end.

Comment: I don't think this reference is relevant to my question above. In this book, I found that Theorems 3.1 and 3.2 consider the stability of an equilibrium, where an equilibrium is defined as $\bar{x}$ that satisfies $f(\bar{x})=0$. I wonder if I'm missing something and if this can be related to my question.